# What is there in the vision of god?

Tags: devi, vision

We have had remarkable saints like Ramakrishna and Bamakhepa who had  the divine vision of goddess. I wanted to know what is there in such a vision , such that they lose tastes in all the other activities in the world? What can the vision of deity impart to us human beings ?